# Is it possible to play with Tigers in Thailand?

Tags: thailand, nature-and-wildlife

A friend of mine told me that some Thai temples holds tigers and that is possible to touch, play with them and take pictures. What are the most famous and safe places to go?

Comment: Before playing with a tiger you might want to watch the movie "The Life of Pi."

Comment: Sitting next to a wild animal isn't a great idea for either you or the animal. How about going on safari and trying to spot one ethically in the wild. https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/animal-selfies-tigers-elephants-the-cruel-truth-thailand-a7623311.html

Comment: Hi @Stuart! I can't tell how embarrassed I feel by looking at this. I was younger and just curious about visiting such amazing animals. I had - really - absolutely no idea how bad treated they are in so many places. My sincere apologies and thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Machado, the fact you are embarrassed is good, means you're a good human. We need more good humans. I went for a ride on a elephant my first time to Africa; something I now deeply regret. Since then I have aimed to see all my wild life in the wild (its way more exciting) and when I do visit rehabilitation centres I do enough research to ensure they are ethical and by visiting I'm not encouraging more suffering.

Answer (score 4):

I'm aware of only two:

[Tiger Temple, close to Kanchanaburi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_Temple)

You can have your picture taken with grown up tigers. Fascinating. I've been here and don't remember young tigers.

[Tiger Kingdom, close to Chiang Mai](http://www.tigerkingdom.com)

Here, the draw is being able to play with young tigers. I've been here, it was awesome.

'safe' is very relative. It's extremely unlikely anything will happen. But, if you decide to play with live tiger tails and have no desire to stop until the tiger in question is thoroughly provoked, you might be in for some unhappy consequences.
if you behave in they way your told to behave, there's no real reason to assume you will not be safe.

Comment: I note that Tiger Kingdom show a [**Gallery Phuket**](http://www.tigerkingdom.com/gallery-phuket/) but that their gallery Chiang Mai is 'under construction' - which may not relate to [**Tyger**](http://www.bl.uk/onlinegallery/takingliberties/staritems/634blaketygerpic.html)  availability

Comment: Hm. So, I suppose they have a presence in Phuket as well.